# How to create new columns based on other columns' values using R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) in r, and I am interested in two columns, df$LEFT and df$RIGHT. I would like to create two new columns such that in df$BEST I have the smaller number between LEFT and RIGHT for each row. Analogously, I want to create the column df$WORST where it is stored the smallest number.

```
ID LEFT RIGHT
1  20   70
2  65   15
3  25   65
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
ID LEFT RIGHT BEST WORST
1  20   70    20   70
2  65   15    15   65
3  25   65    25   65
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmin/pmax` to get the corresponding minimum, maximum values of the two columns

```
transform(df, BEST = pmin(LEFT, RIGHT), WORST = pmax(LEFT, RIGHT))
#  ID LEFT RIGHT BEST WORST
#1  1   20    70   20    70
#2  2   65    15   15    65
#3  3   25    65   25    65
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, LEFT = c(20L, 65L, 25L), RIGHT = c(70L, 
  15L, 65L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I see this solution almost works: I get the column as I wanted them in the Console, but I would like to add them to the dataframe too.
I tried to do the following:

transform(df, df$BEST = pmin(LEFT, RIGHT), df$WORST = pmax(LEFT, RIGHT)) 

But it doesn't work?

Comment: @NobelPrize  just do the assignment `df <- transform(df, ..`

Comment: I feel very embarrassed by it but kudos, you solved my problems ;-)

Comment: @Kundera Not to feel embarrassed.  We all go through the same issues during learning.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using `apply`

```
> df$WORST <- apply(df[,-1], 1, min)
> df$BEST <- apply(df[,-1], 1, max)
> df
  ID LEFT RIGHT WORST BEST
1  1   20    70    20   70
2  2   65    15    15   65
3  3   25    65    25   65
```

Using @akrun's approach with `transform`:

```
> transform(df,
            WORST =  apply(df[,-1], 1, min),
            BEST = apply(df[,-1], 1, max))
```